# Ehcache - Unable to get distributed caching working

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

I am trying to enable distributed caching on ehcache for one of my projects between 2 nodes but I am running into issues.
I am using ehcache core 2.6.11 in a Java Spring project

Here are relevant portions of my ehcache config on each of the servers

**Node 1**

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
    properties="
        peerDiscovery=manual,
        rmiUrls=//node2.mydomain.com:40002/myCache1|//node2.mydomain.com:40002/myCache2"/>

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
    properties="port=40001"/>
```

**Node 2**

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
    properties="
        peerDiscovery=manual,
        rmiUrls=//node1.mydomain.com:40001/myCache1|//node1.mydomain.com:40001/myCache2"/>

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
    properties="port=40002"/>
```

When I update my cache and expect it to be replicated - here are the errors I get on my nodes

**Node 1**

```
03.03.2016 06:44:50 DEBUG [net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProvider.lookupRemoteCachePeer():126] Lookup URL //node2.mydomain.com:40002/myCache1
03.03.2016 06:44:50 WARN  [net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.writeReplicationQueue():325] Unable to send message to remote peer.  Message was: Connection refused to host: <node 2 IP Address>; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: <node 2 IP Address>; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:130)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICachePeer_Stub.send(Unknown Source)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.writeReplicationQueue(RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java:314)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.replicationThreadMain(RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java:127)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.access$000(RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java:58)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator$ReplicationThread.run(RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java:389)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.ConfigurableRMIClientSocketFactory.createSocket(ConfigurableRMIClientSocketFactory.java:70)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
        ... 8 more
```

**Node 2**

```
03.03.2016 06:44:50 DEBUG [net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProvider.lookupRemoteCachePeer():126] Lookup URL //node1.mydomain.com:40001/myCache1
03.03.2016 06:44:50 WARN  [net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.writeReplicationQueue():325] Unable to send message to remote peer.  Message was: Connection refused to host: <node 2 IP Address>; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: <node 2 IP Address>; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:130)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICachePeer_Stub.send(Unknown Source)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.writeReplicationQueue(RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java:314)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.replicationThreadMain(RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java:127)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.access$000(RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java:58)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator$ReplicationThread.run(RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java:389)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.ConfigurableRMIClientSocketFactory.createSocket(ConfigurableRMIClientSocketFactory.java:70)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
        ... 8 more
```

**UPDATE**

I have changed my configuration now to use Automatic Discovery instead of Manual.
I have 4 servers, 2 in Site A and 2 in Site B.
The replicated is now working as expected on Site A between both nodes but no replication is occuring on Site B or between Site A and Site B.

I used netcat and telnet between each node and the other nodes and all connections were accepted.

Here are the relevant sections of my ehcache config for the automatic discovery

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
                                 properties="peerDiscovery=automatic,
                                             multicastGroupAddress=230.3.0.0,
                                             multicastGroupPort=4700,
                                             timeToLive=255"/> 

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
    properties="port=43000, 
                socketTimeoutMillis=20000"/>
```

Could anyone offer any insight into how the replication is not working on Site B or any ideas I could try?

Thanks

Comment: are you using IPV4? If you use IPV6 there could be some problems in ehcache replications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the below steps to fix this issue

1. Add the host name in the Listener as below.

   ```
   <cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
   class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
   properties="hostName=localhost,port=40001"/>
   ```
2. Check the port 40002 is open for access, so that It can be accessed from node1. Means `node2.mydomain.com:40002` should be accessible from node1. From console, you can use `telnet` program to check it. Similarly, check if node1 is accessible from node2. (I believe this is what causing the issue)

Optional: You don't need to have different ports in the two servers. It can have the same port number `40001`.

Comment: I tried that hostname=localhost previously but it threw a warning in the logs - what exactly does that part do?

Comment: It should not throw warning if port 40001 is open in the same host (Point 2 in my answer). This warning must be the tip of iceberg. If you solve it, your problem must be solved

Comment: I have updated my code (and question) to use Automatic discovery but unfortunately still have issues. I tried telent and netcat between all nodes and the connections were open. Any ideas on why ,y replication is only half working at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

I reverted back to the manual discovery approach as we received advice from a Networking specialist that using Multicast accross data centers opens up a whole world of pain.

Using the manual approach with Thanga's suggestions has worked